# Accessing the Metadata API from APEX

Tags: apex, api, metadata-api, metadata

What is the **simplest & easiest** way available to access the Metadata API from APEX (accessing the current Org) **?**

Comment: Downvote for the most blatant lack of research I have seen on this site in quite some time.

Comment: -1 from me for lack of research (given Adrian's answer below)

Comment: The words `simplest` and/or `easiest` are also red flags for an opinionated question.

Comment: @zgc7009 could you provide some refs to that, I am quite new to stack, I'll be glad to learn some good practices for writing questions, thanks

Comment: @benahm You should liberally browse the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask], for starters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Salesforce have released direct support from Apex with Summer 17. Refer to: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2017/05/introducing-apex-metadata-api.html

Answer (score 6):

If you had simply searched google for your very question title, you would have found the answer:

> ## [Apex Wrapper Salesforce Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi)
>
> [image: Deploy to Salesforce]
>
> #### Documentation
>
> In addition to the documentation in this README, the following blogs also cover the library.
>
> - [Automating the Creation of Flow Screens with Apex Metadata API](http://andyinthecloud.com/2015/11/28/automating-the-creation-of-flow-screens-with-apex-metadata-api/)
> - [Apex Metadata API Q&A](http://andyinthecloud.com/2014/11/22/apex-metadata-api-qa/)
> - [Apex Metadata API Streamlined and Simplified for Summer’14](http://andyinthecloud.com/2014/08/14/apex-metadata-api-streamlined-and-simplified-for-summer14/)
> - [Post Install Apex Metadata API Configuration Solved!](http://andyinthecloud.com/2014/07/29/post-install-apex-metadata-api-configuration-solved/)
> - [Apex Metadata API and Spring’14 : Keys to the Kingdom!](http://andyinthecloud.com/2014/04/24/apex-metadata-api-and-spring14-keys-to-the-kingdom/)
> - [Introduction to calling the Metadata API from Apex.](http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/10/27/introduction-to-calling-the-metadata-api-from-apex/)
> - [Spring’14 Pre-Release : Updating Layouts in Apex](http://andyinthecloud.com/category/metadata-api/)
> - [“Look ma, no hands!” : Automating Install and Uninstall of Packages!](http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/06/23/look-ma-no-hands-automating-install-and-uninstall-of-packages/)
> - [Scripting the Apex Metadata API and Batch Apex Support](http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/05/06/scripting-the-apex-metadata-api-and-batch-apex-support/)
> - [Apex Metadata API Spring’13 Update : Org Settings Access](http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/03/10/apex-metadata-api-spring13-update-org-settings-access/)
>
> This API mirrors as much as possible the API types and operations described in the standard documentation. The behaviour and functionality provided is also as described in the Salesforce documentation, in terms of what metadata is available and accessable via the specific operations.
>
> - [Salesforce Metadata API Developers Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/)

Comment: On a related note, Salesforce has [started working on metadata updates via Apex](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l4TkAAI). Until that's delivered though, the metadata api wrapper is pretty much the only decent solution.