# How to get list list of flows accessible by a User based on Permission Sets?

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, metadata-api, permissions, permission-sets

In order to provide more granular and controlled access to flows, all our flows are enabled with access setting of "Override default behavior and restrict access to enabled profiles or permission sets" and access to the flows will be provisioned only using Permission Sets (Permission Set -> Flow Access settings).

We have a requirement to display the list of flows the user has access to based on the permission sets assigned to them. How can we achieve this using SOQL or Apex?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In short: **I managed to do this in Apex by using [apex-mdapi](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) AFTER I updated the code to support flowAccesses.** - here's the [github commit](https://github.com/kg345/apex-mdapi/commit/41522cc16944771555882c101456fa6b738de34a) with changes needed to support it. This is the only way I can see to do this through Apex as you need to hit the Metadata API.

---

*Very Long Version*

I didn't see anything within *SOQL* or *Tooling API* that can be used. It seems like it's **only available with the Metadata API** based on the simple fact that you can retrieve this information with the following package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>test</members>
        <name>PermissionSet</name>
    </types>
<version>47.0</version>
</Package>
```

This returns the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PermissionSet xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <flowAccesses>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <flow>Test_Flow_Name</flow>
    </flowAccesses>
    <hasActivationRequired>false</hasActivationRequired>
    <label>test</label>
    <license>Salesforce</license>
</PermissionSet>
```

That leaves you with trying to use Apex and the Metadata API. This isn't a supported type for what [Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_metadata_supported_types.htm) provides access to through Apex. **Likewise, I don't see any mention of flow access in the [Metadata API Developer Guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/api_meta.pdf)** which puzzled me. However, they do list the other naming conventions for other "access" types:

```
PermissionSetApplicationVisibility[] 
PermissionSetApexClassAccess[]
PermissionSetCustomMetadtaTypeAccess[] 
etc.
```

So now I looked towards **apex-mdapi** which does allow you to interact with apex/Metadata API

You can see the code/github [here](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) and this is a [helpful answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/165173/accessing-the-metadata-api-from-apex) with links to many questions concerning it. I had to make edits to it since it hasn't been updated since `flowAccesses` was brought into play. I used `customMetadataTypeAccess` (which is also relatively new) as a test since that one is at least documented in the developer guide.

You can see my changes in my [forked repo](https://github.com/kg345/apex-mdapi) and the latest commits contains all the changes needed for this in particular. Based on the naming convention in the developer guide (and testing that `PermissionSetCustomMetadataTypeAccess[]` worked first), I used `PermissionSetFlowAccess[]` and the example of the returned retrieve file to populate what the field names would be. You can see that the name of the flow is stored in `<flow></flow>`

---

So now, going off all that above...

Depending on when/where your code is executing, you'd probably first want to get a list of permission sets assigned to the user using SOQL. From [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000319607&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1), you can see the following should do the trick

```
SELECT PermissionSet.Name FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE AssigneeId = 'User Name here'
```

Once you have a list of permission set names, you can call the Metadata API through the `MetadataService` you modified above to simply get those permission sets returned and loop through them to get a list of the Flows they have access to.

```
public class testmetadata {

    public static MetadataService.MetadataPort createService()
    { 
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
        service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
        service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
        return service;     
    }
 
    public static void testPerm()
    {
        //presumably you'd pass this list based on the SOQL query
        String[] permissionSetNames = new String[] {'test', 'test2', 'test3'};

        String message = '';
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();
        List<MetadataService.PermissionSet> perm = (List<MetadataService.PermissionSet>) service.readMetadata('PermissionSet', permissionSetNames).getRecords();

        //loop through returned permission sets based on the names assigned to user
        for(MetadataService.PermissionSet permSet : perm){
            message = permSet.fullName + ' with access to the following flow(s): ';
            //loop through flows that are enabled for access in each perm set to display name
            for(MetadataService.PermissionSetFlowAccess singleFlow : permSet.flowAccesses){
               message += singleFlow.flow + ', ';
            }
            System.debug(message);
        }
    }
}
```

What I tested (using only 3 different flows):

- Created 3 permission sets - test1, test2, test3
- Gave test1 access to    one flow
- Gave test2 access to 2 flows
- Gave test3 access to 3 flows

See the debug log returned below:

[image]

Update: Just to show that the assumptions I made above for the naming convention at least are now corroborated by info in the [Metadata API WSDL](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dev_wsdl.htm&type=5). You can see the naming for Profile and Permission Set.

[image]

[image]

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your time to answer this question.Its very detailed. I am facing this error when testing the code from your repo - "Line: 13496, Column: 1
System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: UNSUPPORTED_API_VERSION: Invalid Api version specified on URL faultcode=sf:UNSUPPORTED_API_VERSION faultactor="

 Do I need to update something?

Comment: I'm using api 48 so it must be a Spring 20 sandbox. You can change it to 47.0 as I think flowaccess should be available. I'll edit when I get a chance with my testing with 47.0

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Can you please update it to 47 whenever possible?

Comment: Just to add, I changed the version to 47.0 and it worked fine. Thank you again for helping with it.

Comment: Just pushed the commit. Forgot I was testing this in my Spring 20 dev org. Should work now. All I changed was the `endpoint_x` to be `/services/Soap/m/47.0`

Comment: This rocks. I would very much love it if you would now turn this code into one or more invocable actions and then post about it on unofficialsf.com. There is tremendous potential for declarative actions that allow admins to benefit from the powerful combination of MetadataService, Apex, and Flow. I'm working on some right now that pull in Approval Process metadata and expose useful actions in Flow screens. Just sayin'. =)

Comment: `<flowAccesses>` isn't documented as an element for either [MDAPI Profile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm?search_text=flowaccesses) or [MDAPI PermissionSet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_permissionset.htm?search_text=flowaccesses) - so I'm surprised this worked.

Comment: @cropredy - `flowaccesses` now appears in the Metadata API WSDL! Still not in the documentation though.

Comment: I noticed in [Gearset doc](https://gearset.com/blog/what-is-the-salesforce-metadata-flowaccesses)  that `flowAccesses` could be obtained if the retrieve included `Profile` and `FlowDefinition`. Is that what you observe?

Comment: I'm actually a Gearset user that also chatted/worked through that with them (even shared this answer with them) and that's what I observed (for `profiles`). It seems `flowAccesses` is returned for all flows with `FlowDefinition` and `Profile` (even if false). For PermissionSet, it only returns if it's `true`.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves stumbled on this whilst manually converting a profile XML to become a Perm Set XML and went a-hunting. I'm puzzled, even with what little documentation SF released for this; they use the term "access" to the flow, but what does this mean? Does it mean the flow can be executed in the context of the user, or that the user can view the metadata for the flow? Did you figure this out?

Comment: @PhilW - When you click on the dropdown of the flow row in setup, you should see an "Edit Access" button. There, you can configure your flow to `Override default behavior and restrict access to enabled profiles or permission sets`. This flowaccess is related to that - giving the user with the permissionset/profile ability to run a flow set up to be restricted by profile/permissionset access

Comment: @KrisGoncalves, thanks. I wonder what happens when the user isn't given permission to run a flow that is an auto-launch before record save flow... hmm...

Answer (score 0):

As of API version 58, you can:

Step 1) Query [`SetupEntityAccess`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_setupentityaccess.htm)

```
SELECT Id, SetupEntityType, SetupEntityId 
FROM SetupEntityAccess 
WHERE ParentId = :permSetId AND SetupEntityType = "FlowDefinition"
```

Step 2) Make a second query on [`FlowDefinitionView`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_flowdefinitionview.htm) using the resulting `SetupEntityId` list:

```
SELECT DurableId, Label
FROM FlowDefinitionView
WHERE DurableId IN :setupEntityIdList
```

NOTE: As of this posting, the Object reference documentation for `SetupEntityAccess` has not yet been updated to reflect that the field `SetupEntityType` includes "FlowDefinition", but its working in practice.