# Flow Quick Action: "The data you were trying to access could not be found. It may be due to another user deleting the data or a system error"

Tags: visual-workflow, lightning-quickaction

When clicking on a Flow Quick Action, I get the following popup on the screen -- really ugly error message

[image]

### Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following bits in the error message are completely irrelevant to diagnosing this issue in this context:

- There is no data being accessed;
- There is no other user deleting the data

What is the case is the following:

- User **has** Run Flows permission (as Flow User, in Profile, or Permission Set)
- The Flow is configured so as to override default behavior as shown below. This is `<isAdditionalPermissionRequiredToRun>true</isAdditionalPermissionRequiredToRun>` in the MDAPI for `Flow`.
- The running user **has not been** granted permission to run the specific Flow (via Profile or Permission Set)

Normally, you would deploy for `myFlow` the allowed permissions/profiles that you configured in your dev org to your staging/PROD orgs. But, as of V48.0, these Flow Permissions aren't available in the MDAPI `<flowAccesses>..</flowAccesses>`. (see [contradictory evidence](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/291127/2602) -- I could not get these to appear using Workbench retrieve in either V47 or 48 though or using my devops vendor tool)

As such, if you have such a flow with `Override default behavior and restrict access to enabled profiles or permission sets", you may need to manually configure the flow access in your downstream orgs.

[image]

> UPDATE: in v48, if you include `FlowDefinition`, you will get `<flowAccesses>`